# Artifactory: symlink or aliasing an Artifact URL?

Tags: artifactory

I realize that the Artifactory support team reads these SO posts, so my question is either a regular question or a feature request.

I want to programmatically update various artifacts and when my operations complete (copies, writes, moves, deletes), create an alias/symlink to the new/updated artifact URLs.

For example, I would like to have a "latest" link which always points to the latest build for a number of different artifacts: Java, yum, Python and generic binaries, that is, native executables that do not use pypy/Maven/yum toolsets.

I don't see a way to do this and if that is the case, I'd like to request this feature in a new version of Artifactory.

Comment: Did you consider doing it with a [User Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) ?  You can do something like search for the artifact you want  based on whatever custom criteria you decide on and then serve it back with the response or return the download link to it for the client to follow.

Comment: Actually, I ended up doing exactly this, it appears to work exactly how I want it to except that I don't see a "latest" link in the UI since it of course doesn't exist.  Not a huge issue though, I tag the parent directory with a "latest" property which holds the version of the corresponding latest child directory.


I used this script as a starting point: https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/development/download/internalRewriteDownload/internalRewriteDownload.groovy

Thanks @fundeldman!

Comment: Interestingly, I ran into an issue with virtual repositories - my plugin doesn't work with them because path resolution with virtual repos appears to use a different code path i.e. doesn't pass through beforeDownloadRequest.  I ended up scripting this in Lua in my Nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: Follow up - I ended up making this work with virtual and concrete repos by creating a plugin which handled afterDownloadErrors with "latest" link requests.

Comment: FYI, the script link above no longer works, but you can use: https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/download/internalRewriteDownload/internalRewriteDownload.groovy