# Can maven artifactid and version be excluded from dependency resolution URL

Tags: maven, artifactory

I use artifactory to store the built jar files and I am encountering an issue while resolving the artifacts.

I upload to `<artifactory>/snapshots/java/nightly/25/testdemo-2.0.jar`
For maven to do dependency resolution correctly, it should be under 
`<artifactory>/snapshots/java/nightly/25/testdemo/2.0/testdemo-2.0.jar`

Is there anyway to instruct maven to resolve dependency from a URL or just ignore the `artifactID/version/artifact` constraint when it downloads dependency?

Comment: How and why do you _upload_ rather than `mvn deploy` and why has the directory to be non-Maven-compliant?

Comment: Thats how artifactory plugin does it. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-UploadingandDownloadingFiles

Comment: there are hundreds of jars in such state already. I dont want to be the person cleaning up maven repo for other teams

Comment: Apparently if one uses _Uploading and Downloading Files_ but there's another section [_Maven Builds with Artifactory_](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-MavenBuildswithArtifactory). "_Hundreds_" sounds awful. How do they resolve them or did that in the past?

Comment: By pulling it to disk ! also majority of them are release products

Comment: So they all work just with the local repository. That's the craziest thing I've ever heard in conjunction with Maven, by far. I even refuse just to think of all the issues that may crop out with that. +1 for compassion. Perhaps [Artifactory: symlink or aliasing an Artifact URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40661376/1744774) helps you in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` (a.k.a. *GAV*) are not a "*constraint*" but [*Maven coordinates*](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) which are essential to identify an artifact both logically (in a POM) and physically (in a repository). I'm not aware of any way to overcome this and if there were one I'd not recommend it under any circumstances. You'd confuse and trick out the rest of the Maven world by doing this.

Comment: As @Gerold wrote, overwriting the Maven coordinates is a bad practice and very not recommended.

Comment: Can a single pom.xml produce multiple jar files? I ask because i can detect the artifactid and version from pom.xml

Comment: @kbang Yes, but not with different GAV, but with an added classifier to the artifact's name only. See [How to create an additional attached jar artifact from the project](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/attached-jar.html).